# *ngIf on Ionic 2 not work with binding

Tags: ionic-framework, data-binding, ionic2

I'm Trying to hide/show elements of a `ion-list` depending of a boolean variable which is changed when a button is clicked.

The problem is that if I try with `*ngIf="{{editMode}}"` the `ionic serve --lab` shows blank screen on browser.

```
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="itemTapped($event, item)">
      <ion-item>

        <ion-icon item-left name="rose" *ngIf="{{editMode}}"></ion-icon>

        <ion-icon name="{{item.icon}}" item-left></ion-icon>
        {{item.title}}
        <div class="item-note" item-right>
          {{item.note}}
        </div>

      </ion-item>
```

And if i try with `*ngIf="'editMode'"` the result of click on button is nothing.

When I click on a nav bar button the boolen variable is modified to true/false.

What would be wrong?

Comment: when you do `*ngIf="{{editMode}}"` any logs in the console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngIf)

You have to do `*ngIf="editMode"`

`*ngIf="'editMode'"` - Here you are just taking the *string* editMode which is **truthy** and button will not work.

Comment: `*ngIf="editMode"` works fine but with `*ngIf="{{editMode}}"` doesn`t works.